# Sorting multiple data members

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

What should be the best approach to make multiple sortings in vector of pointers (`std::vector<SomeObject*`)? Should I make one sorting function for multiple data members and what would be the best way to do it? Or maybe I should make separate functions for each data member? Or maybe i should use some things from `std::sort()`?
Let's say i have some class Vehicle with some data members

```
    class Vehicle{
    private:
        unsigned int _maxSpeed;
        unsigned short _numberOfHorsePower;
        unsigned short _numberOfGears;
        unsigned short _numberOfWheels;
        unsigned int _weight;
    }
```

And I would like to have option to sort those objects by each data member e.g `SortByMaxSpeedAsc()`,`SortByWeightAsc()`,`SortByWeightDesc()`.

sample sorting of one data member

```
    void Vehicles::sortVehiclesByWeightAsc()
    {
        Vehicle* tmp;
        size_t n = _VehiclesCollection.size();
        int i, j, minIndex;
    
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        {
            minIndex = i;
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
            {
                if (_VehiclesCollection[j].weight < _VehiclesCollection[minIndex].weight)
                {
                    minIndex = j;
                }
            }
    
            if (minIndex != i) 
            {
                tmp = _VehiclesCollection[i];
                _VehiclesCollection[i] = _VehicleCollection[minIndex];
                _VehiclesCollection[minIndex] = tmp;
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `std::sort` with custom comparer.

Comment: You can make projections: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e4aa7971dd9fc2d

Comment: It seems ts ask about multiple sortings, that is array that sorted by criterion 1 taken separately. And simultaneously the same array at the same time  sorted by criterion 2. I.e. independently. And possible duplicate says about single sorting : by criterion 1 and within the same values of criterion 1 also sorted by criterion 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and write a `Compare` functor for each of your cases. If you need to combine multiple fields, use [std::tie](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

Here's an example. You don't need to make the sorting functions `static` members like I've done here but it makes it possible to use `std::tie` with private members.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Vehicle {
public:
    Vehicle(unsigned maxSpeed, unsigned short numberOfHorsePower,
            unsigned short numberOfGears, unsigned short numberOfWheels,
            unsigned weight) :
        maxSpeed_(maxSpeed),
        numberOfHorsePower_(numberOfHorsePower), numberOfGears_(numberOfGears),
        numberOfWheels_(numberOfWheels), weight_(weight) {}

    // you can use the accessor functions with loose sort statements if you don't
    // need to tie many columns together

    inline unsigned get_maxSpeed() const { return maxSpeed_; }
    inline unsigned short get_numberOfHorsePower() const {
        return numberOfHorsePower_;
    }
    inline unsigned short get_numberOfGears() const { return numberOfGears_; }
    inline unsigned short get_numberOfWheels() const { return numberOfWheels_; }
    inline unsigned get_weight() const { return weight_; }

    // sorting functions

    template<typename It>
    static void sort_on_speed(It first, It last) {
        std::sort(first, last,
            // a lambda receiving references to two Vehicle objects to compare
            [](const Vehicle& a, const Vehicle& b) {
                // return true if a is less than b (using the field you want)
                return a.maxSpeed_ < b.maxSpeed_;
            }
       );
    }

    template<typename It>
    static void sort_on_hp_plus_speed(It first, It last) {
        std::sort(first, last,
            // another lambda using std::tie to sort primarily on hp
            // and secondary on speed
            [](const Vehicle& a, const Vehicle& b) {
                return std::tie(a.numberOfHorsePower_, a.maxSpeed_) <
                       std::tie(b.numberOfHorsePower_, b.maxSpeed_);
        });
    }

private:
    unsigned int maxSpeed_;
    unsigned short numberOfHorsePower_;
    unsigned short numberOfGears_;
    unsigned short numberOfWheels_;
    unsigned int weight_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Vehicle> cars = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}, {3, 4, 5, 1, 2}
    };

    // sort on speed
    Vehicle::sort_on_speed(cars.begin(), cars.end());

    // sort on hp + speed
    Vehicle::sort_on_hp_plus_speed(cars.begin(), cars.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`boost.multiindex`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html) should be very useful.